# Convert a docker run command into a docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I want to run this in my Docker Swarm:

```
docker run --rm -it progrium/stress --cpu 2 --io 1 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 10s
```

so I need a Docker-compose.yml

How should I use this docker image in a docker compose and pass those params ?

Comment: Have you read through the [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)?

Comment: also check out [composerize.com](https://composerize.com)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Converting a docker run command into a compose file

[Composerize](https://composerize.com) will help you convert run command to a compose partially.

To understand it better I have described the components of the `docker-compose.yml` here.

`image` - image used to run the container

`name` - name of the service or container

`command` - command you want to run after the container is up

`volumes` - volume(s) you want to mount

Converting the run command from above to docker-compose:

```
version: "2/3/3.3/3.6" # based on the docker-compose version you use
services:
   stress: # Service name, user defined
      image: progrium/stress 
      command: '--cpu 2 --io 1 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 10s'
```

First two lines are common for any docker-compose file.

In docker-compose, the `command` allows the image to accept additional commands or options.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
   stress:
      image: progrium/stress
      command: '--cpu 2 --io 1 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 10s'
```

Compose the file with docker-compose as:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

- Multiple commands to the compose file:

  `command: bash -c "cd app/ && npm start"`
- Multi-line command to compose file:

  ```
  command: >
    bash -c "cd app/ 
    && npm start"
  ```

```html
<embed src="https://composerize.com/"  width="100%" height="700">
```

Comment: I am looking for a tool that does the opposite - creates docker run commands from a docker compose file. Is there one?

Answer (score 19):

Just use this nifty little tool as a helper: https://composerize.com/

Or follow the manual steps highlighted in the previous answers...

Comment: This tool is nice but is very limited for some docker run commands.

Comment: BTW, it runs from CLI too: https://github.com/magicmark/composerize#cli

Answer (score 18):

[This tool](https://8gwifi.org/dc1.jsp) will help you convert docker run command to a docker-compose most of the feature

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Compose file's [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) or [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) keyword. It is straightforward to translate a `docker run` command into declarations in the docker-compose.yml file.

To use the `command` keyword in your docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  stress:
    image: progrium/stress
    command:
    - --cpu 2
    - --io 1
    - --vm 2
    - --vm-bytes 128M
    - --timeout 10s
```

To use the `entrypoint` keyword in your docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  stress:
    image: progrium/stress
    entrypoint:
    - <entrypoint name to override the original one>
    - --cpu 2
    - --io 1
    - --vm 2
    - --vm-bytes 128M
    - --timeout 10s
```